# Embedded static content in self hosting Nancy instance

Tags: c#, nancy

I have a self hosting Nancy instance and embedded the content in the assembly (a few sshtml views and a few css files)

This is the content of my DefaultNancyBootstrapper

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    private byte[] favicon;

    protected override byte[] FavIcon
    {
        get { return this.favicon ?? (this.favicon = LoadFavIcon()); }
    }

    private byte[] LoadFavIcon()
    {
        using (var resourceStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FrontEnd.Webinterface.Views.Content.Images.Icons.FavIcon.ico"))
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            resourceStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        }
    }

    protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            return NancyInternalConfiguration.WithOverrides(OnConfigurationBuilder);
        }
    }

    void OnConfigurationBuilder(NancyInternalConfiguration x)
    {
        x.ViewLocationProvider = typeof(ResourceViewLocationProvider);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string[] assemblyNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
        ResourceViewLocationProvider.RootNamespaces.Add(
          Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainModule)), "FrontEnd.Webinterface.Views");
    }

    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        CookieBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules
    {
        get
        {
            return

                AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner
                    .TypesOf<INancyModule>(ScanMode.All)
                    .NotOfType<DiagnosticModule>()
                    .Select(t => new ModuleRegistration(t))
                    .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm completely stuck how to embed my static CSS files - Can anyone help me out?

EDIT:

Solution is quite simple if this is in your Nancy Assembly https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Embedded/Conventions/EmbeddedStaticContentConventionBuilder.cs

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
        {
            Assembly Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(EmbeddedStaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("Static", Assembly, @"Webinterface/Static"));
            nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("Views", @"Webinterface/Views"));
        }
```

Comment: *and embedded the content in the assembly* - explain please? These static files do not normally get bundled into assemblies. Can you also elaborate on your solution structure a little. Thanks

Comment: I have a solution which contains a few Windows forms and the Nancy webinterface as a self hosting instance. I would like to have a solution which works completely out-of-the-box, which contains all *,dll, Nancy views, Images, CSS in that one .exe file I will distribute. So yes, I also embed these static files like CSS and images.

Comment: Why do you want this? Why is it important that everything is a single exe?

Comment: I just want it :) My app should be portable. I don't like many dependency-files around my .exe file. I want my whole project is working just out of the box of this single executable. I can imagine this is not best practice, but I would like to have this "feature".

Comment: OK well it is unorthodox but I guess possible, but no idea how you're going to do it. I've removed my answer as it's not helpful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already answered your question yourself I'd like to add a couple of lines regarding the solution that worked fine for me.

First of all here are some links with the discussion on the topic containing explanations how things work:

- Embedded content in Nancy on Google groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nancy-web-framework/N3neO1FJ3Qc
- [Build Simple Web UIs with the Nancy Framework (see section "Delivering the Web UI")](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/03/01/Simple-Web-UIs-with-the-Nancy-Framework.aspx)

Second, instead of `EmbeddedStaticContentConventionBuilder` that you mentioned in your question I used implementation based on the source code from the second link by Patrick Steele, which is much simpler:

```
public static class StaticResourceConventionBuilder
{
    public static Func<NancyContext, string, Response> AddDirectory(string requestedPath, Assembly assembly, string namespacePrefix)
    {
        return (context, s) =>
        {
            var path = context.Request.Path;

            if (!path.StartsWith(requestedPath))
            {
                return null;
            }

            string resourcePath;
            string name;

            var adjustedPath = path.Substring(requestedPath.Length + 1);

            if (adjustedPath.IndexOf('/') >= 0)
            {
                name = Path.GetFileName(adjustedPath);
                resourcePath = namespacePrefix + "." + adjustedPath
                    .Substring(0, adjustedPath.Length - name.Length - 1)
                    .Replace('/', '.');
            }
            else
            {
                name = adjustedPath;
                resourcePath = namespacePrefix;
            }

            return new EmbeddedFileResponse(assembly, resourcePath, name);
        };
    }
}
```

And then

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
    {
        base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);

        nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions
            .Add(StaticResourceConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/Scripts", GetType().Assembly, "MyAssembly.Scripts"));
    }
}
```